# How can I track a users storage usage in Amazon S3?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am designing a react app (with mySQL as my backend) which allows users to add photos to an Amazon S3 bucket; however, I can't find any information on how I can keep track of a users current storage usage.

One way I am thinking of solving this is by simply adding a column in my mySQL database and adding/removing the file size whenever a user uploads/deletes a photo.

The only issue I am having is that this does not seem like an efficient solution. Any advice or knowledge shared is appreciated.

Comment: That's how you would do that. You can use different db, dynamodb, if you don't want to modify your mysql.

Comment: Modifying my db is not a problem. I was more interested in whether or not it is an efficient method. Thanks.